# What is an example of a Node that isn't an Element?

Tags: javascript, xmlnode

What is an example of a Node that isn't an Element? Are elements created from the HTML the same "type" as elements created from JS? (I.e. are they both of type Element?) How does one make a Node which *isn't* an Element?

Comment: textNodes have data instead of innerHTML. "<b> hi </b>" has two nodes: the Element B, and the textNode " hi ". there are also comment nodes, attribute nodes (deprecated), and a few others i can't recall...

Comment: I don't know if I get you correctly do you mean something like text nodes? you can create one using: `document.createTextNode('string')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most promiment ones are text nodes, without whom a page might have a structure but no content.

You can create them with  [`document.createTextNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createTextNode) (in contrast to `document.createElement`).

Other types of [nodes](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#nodes) include:

- Document
- DocumentFragment
- DocumentType
- ProcessingInstruction
- Comment

In [(current) DOM3](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1590626202) there are also EntityReference, CDATASection, Notation and Attribute nodes. These were however never really used, and are deprecated in the DOM4 draft.

Comment: Thanks for the link. So from what I've gathered, all of the normal elements (p, div, script, etc.) are of type Element, regardless of whether they're created by the browser or by a script.

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius: Whether something is parsed from HTML or created by JS doesn't make a difference. The DOM is the DOM.

Comment: Yes - all "elements" are `Element` nodes. However, in the DOM tree there are also other types of nodes, e.g. `Document` nodes (in the root)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [MDN page for Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node), you could create:

- text node - [`document.createTextNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.createTextNode)
- document fragment - [`document.createDocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.createDocumentFragment)
- comment - [`document.createComment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.createComment)
- CDATA section - [`document.createCDATASection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.createCDATASection)
- entity reference - [`document.createEntityReference`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.createEntityReference)
- processing instruction - [`document.createProcessingInstruction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.createProcessingInstruction)

Note that some of those might not be widely supported, i.e. `document.createFragment` is supported in Chrome and Firefox only so far, others might be depreceated, i.e. entity references.